# Symfony: how to check if a variable saved in sfContext is set or not?

Tags: symfony1

i have this code:

```
if(sfContext::getInstance()->get('form_signin')){

     //...

}
```

but im getting this error:

> The "form_signin" object does not
>   exist in the current context.

Any right way to check if a variable saved in sfContext is set or not ?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the "has" call rather than the get

```
if(sfContext::getInstance()->has('form_signin')){

     //...

}
```

Comment: On a side note, sfContext should never be used like that as it's a singleton class. (so it should only be initialised once)

Read: http://webmozarts.com/2009/07/01/why-sfcontextgetinstance-is-bad/

:-)